# How to install ipa file (no jailbreak)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I uploaded this ipa file on the website https://www.diawi.com/
I tried to install on the phone but it respond "Ongame could not be installed at this time."
I tried to sign again but still failed.
Please guide me to edit this ipa file so I can install it on my iphone.
Link file: http://ongame.tk/file/Ongame240.ipa
[image http://ongame.tk/file/err.jpg](http://ongame.tk/file/err.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this website https://www.diawi.com/ to share `ipa` file.

To share your app `ipa` file via [this](https://www.diawi.com/) website you have to follow these steps:

- First add devices(iPhone where you will try to install your app) `UDID` to your Apple developer account.
- Then add these devices into your app Development `Provisioning Profiles`.
- Now generate and download these profiles.
- Use these profiles to create Development `ipa` file.
- Upload this `ipa` to https://www.diawi.com/ and share the genearted link with those people whose device UDID you have added in `Provisioning profile`.

**Note:** Person who is trying to install may have to trust your provisioning profile in his/her device.

You can also checkout Diawi knowledge base [Can't install an app on a device? Things to check](https://www.diawi.com/knowledge-base/iOS/Cant-install-an-app-on-a-device-things-to-check)

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Is there another way to install on my iphone, I don't have the source code of this game.

Comment: No, without jailbreaking you cannot install ipa file if your device UDID is not add in ipa file

Comment: Thanks for supporting me

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to make any changes with the ipa file, you have to rebuild and create a separate ipa with the updated provisioning profile.